# Marginal density using lebesgue integral

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory

If we have two random variables X and Y with a joint density function $f_{XY}(x,y)$. How can I express the marginal density functions $f_{X}(x)$ and $f_{Y}(y)$ using the Lebesgue integral? I know that

$f_{X}(x) = \int^\infty_{-\infty}f_{XY}(x,y)dy$
$f_{Y}(y) = \int^\infty_{-\infty}f_{XY}(x,y)dx$

but how can I express these integrations using the Lebesgue integration without using the Lebesgue measure and without using the change of variable formula?

Thanks

Comment: But this is already Lebesgue integration...

Comment: I am sorry, I am confused , how is this Lebesgue integration? don't we need to integrate with respect to a certain measure?

Comment: Here it's the Lebesgue measure *on the real line*.

Comment: I am sorry, I still don't get it. because I always look at how we find the expectation, for example $E[X] = \int x f_{X}(x) dx$ but using Lebesgue integral $E[X] = \int X dP$ , so in the Lebesgue integral $f_{X}(x)$ and $dx$ are not used. So I how can I apply the same principle to the marginal density?

Comment: Ok, @Jasmine I leave it to an expert in probability :)

Comment: @Jasmine Maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) helps

Comment: @Fakemistake I want to write the integration with respect to $dP$, something similar to the way we write the expectation